# Реализация записи и считывания данных с помощью массива структур

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream, файловый-ввод-вывод, binary-file

Необходимо разработать программу, имеющую два режима работы. Режим выбирается пользователем с клавиатуры.

Вывод данных на экран в виде таблицы оформить как функцию `void print_data(const <ваш тип структуры> *data, std::size_t len, std::ostream &ost)`, где `data` — указатель на массив структур длины `len`, `ost` — выходной поток в текстовом режиме.

Режим 1

Считать данные из текстового файла в массив структур. Оформить как функцию `<ваш тип структуры> *load_txt(std::istream &ist, std::size_t &len)`, где `ist` — входной поток в текстовом режиме, которая возвращает указатель на созданный массив структур, `len` — выходной параметр, куда записывается длина массива.
Вывести данные на экран в виде таблицы.
Сохранить данные в соответствии с вариантом в двоичном файле. Оформить как функцию `void save_bin(const <ваш тип структуры> *data, std::size_t len, std::ostream &ost)`, где data — указатель на массив структур длины `len`, `ost` — выходной поток в двоичном режиме.

Режим 2

Считать данные из двоичного файла в массив структур. Оформить как функцию  `<ваш тип структуры> *load_bin(std::istream &ist, std::size_t &len)`, где `ist` — входной поток в двоичном режиме, которая возвращает указатель на созданный массив структур, len — выходной параметр, куда записывается длина массива.
Вывести данные на экран в виде таблицы.

Вот то что получилось у меня, не понимаю как обработать enum c типами книг и как правильно считать данные из массива структур в файл

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Определение структуры Журнал
struct Journal
{
char Name[20];
int Cost; //Беззнаковая стоимость
int Count;

enum Journal_Subject
{
    FORKIDS, //0
    SCIENCEPOP, //1
    POP, //2
    SCIENCE //3
};
};

//Поле для выбора
int _stateMenu;
void Menu()
{
    cout << "Выберите режим работы программы" << endl
        << " (0) Выход из программы" << endl
        << " (1) Режим 1" << endl
        << " (2) Режим 2" << endl
        << "Ваш выбор: " << endl;
    //Считыание выбора пользователя
    cin >> _stateMenu;
}

//Считывание массива структуры
void load_txt(Journal* &journal_elements, int& number_elements, istream& input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements; i++)
    {

        input >> journal_elements[i].Name;
        input >> journal_elements[i].Cost;
        input >> journal_elements[i].Count;

        //TODO: Настроить работу с enum
        /*input >> journal_elements[i].forkids;*/
        input.get();

    }
}

void load_bin(Journal*& journal_elements, int& number_elements, istream& input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements; i++)
    {
        input >>  journal_elements[i].Name;
        input >>  journal_elements[i].Cost;
        input >>  journal_elements[i].Count;
    }
}

//Вывод таблицы на экран
void print_data(Journal* journal_elements, int number_elements, ostream& output)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(30) << left << journal_elements[i].Name << "\t";
        cout << setw(30) << left << journal_elements[i].Cost << "\t";
        cout << setw(30) << left << journal_elements[i].Count << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
}



void save_bin(Journal *journal_elements,int number_elements,ostream& output)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < number_elements; i++)
    {
        output << journal_elements[i].Name << '\t';
        output << setw(30) << right << journal_elements[i].Cost << '\t';
        output << setw(30) << right << journal_elements[i].Count << '\t';
        output << endl;
    }

}


int main()
   {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
                      
    ifstream input("D:\\Учёба 1 курс\\ОП\\2 Семестр\\Практическая работа №16\\PracticeWork 16\\In.txt.txt",ios::in);
    ofstream output("D:\\Учёба 1 курс\\ОП\\2 Семестр\\Практическая работа №16\\PracticeWork 16\\Out_bin.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    

    Menu();

    if (!input.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не открыт!" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //Массив структур

        int number_elements = 4;
        
        Journal* journal_elements = new Journal[number_elements];

        while (_stateMenu != 0)
        {
            switch (_stateMenu)
            {
            case 1:

                //TODO: Режим работы 1
                cout << "Режим работы 1" << endl;

                cout << "Считывание данных из текстового файла в массив структур" << endl
                    << "Вывести данные на экран таблицей" << endl
                    << "Сохранить данные в двоичный файл" << endl
                    << endl;


                //Cчитывание данных в массив структур
                load_txt(journal_elements, number_elements, input);

                print_data(journal_elements, number_elements, output);

                save_bin((journal_elements), number_elements, output);
                break;

            case 2:
                //TODO: Режим работы 2
                cout << "Режим работы 2" << endl;

                cout << "Считать данные из двоичного файла в массив структур" << endl
                    << "Вывод данных в виде таблицы" << endl
                    << endl;

                load_bin(journal_elements, number_elements, input);

                print_data(journal_elements, number_elements, output);

                break;
            }

            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Файл для чтения имеет следующий вид:

```
НЕПОСЕДА            100 10 1
ИНТЕРНАУКА          200 5 2
НАУКА               120 2 3
GQ                  250 20 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам в этом вопросе, вдруг кому пригодится! Всем мир!

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

//Определение структуры Журнал
struct Journal
{
    enum Journal_Subject
    {
        FORKIDS, //0
        SCIENCEPOP, //1
        POP, //2
        SCIENCE, //3
        UNKNOWN //4
    };

    char Name[20];
    unsigned int Cost; //Беззнаковая стоимость
    int Count;
    Journal_Subject Subject;



    string Subject_To_String()
    {
        switch (Subject)
        {
        case Journal::FORKIDS:
            return "детский";
            break;
        case Journal::SCIENCEPOP:
            return "научно-популярный";
            break;
        case Journal::POP:
            return "популярный";
            break;
        case Journal::SCIENCE:
            return "научный";
            break;
        default:
            return "неизвестный";
            break;
        }
    }
    void Set_Subject(string s)
    {
        if (s == "forkids")
        {
            Subject = Journal::FORKIDS;
        }
        else if (s == "science-pop")
        {
            Subject = Journal::SCIENCEPOP;
        }
        else if (s == "popular")
        {
            Subject = Journal::POP;
        }
        else if (s == "science")
        {
            Subject = Journal::SCIENCE;
        }
        else
        {
            Subject = Journal::UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
};


//Поле для выбора
int Menu()
{
    int state;
    cout << "Выберите режим работы программы" << endl
        << " (0) Выход из программы" << endl
        << " (1) Режим 1" << endl
        << " (2) Режим 2" << endl
        << "Ваш выбор: " << endl;
    //Считыание выбора пользователя
    cin >> state;
    return state;
}

//Считывание массива структуры
Journal* load_txt(istream& ist, size_t& len)
{
    Journal* data = nullptr;
    //пытаемся прочитать количество записей
    ist >> len;
    if (!ist.fail() && !ist.eof())//если успешно прочиталось и не конец файла
    {
        data = new Journal[len]; //инициализируем массив
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            string subject; //переменная для считывания строки тематики
            ist >> data[i].Name
                >> data[i].Cost
                >> data[i].Count
                >> subject;

            if (ist.fail()) { // если не всё успешно прочиталось
                len = 0; //обнуляем количество
                delete[] data; //удаляем массив
                data = nullptr;
                cout << "Ошибка чтения файла" << endl;
                break; //выходим из цикла
            }
            data[i].Set_Subject(subject); //определяем соответствие строки к enum
        }
    }
    else
    {
        len = 0;
        cout << "Ошибка чтения файла" << endl;
    }

    return data;
}

Journal* load_bin(istream& ist, size_t& len)
{
    Journal* data = nullptr;
    //пытаемся прочитать количество записей
    ist.read((char*)&len, sizeof(len));
    if (!ist.fail() && !ist.eof())//если успешно прочиталось и не конец файла
    {
        data = new Journal[len]; //инициализируем массив
        ist.read((char*)data, (uint64_t)len * sizeof(Journal)); //заливаем байты в массив
        if (ist.fail())// если не всё успешно прочиталось
        {
            len = 0; //обнуляем количество
            delete[] data; //удаляем массив
            data = nullptr;
            cout << "Ошибка чтения файла" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        len = 0;
        cout << "Ошибка чтения файла" << endl;
    }
    return data;
}

//Вывод таблицы на экран
void print_data(Journal* data, int len)
{
    //выводим поля в виде таблицы с шириной ячейки 30 символов и выравниванием по левому краю

    cout << setw(30) << left << "Название";
    cout << setw(30) << left << "Стоимость";
    cout << setw(30) << left << "Количество";
    cout << setw(30) << left << "Тематика";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(30) << left << data[i].Name;
        cout << setw(30) << left << data[i].Cost;
        cout << setw(30) << left << data[i].Count;
        cout << setw(30) << left << data[i].Subject_To_String();
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//сортировка пузырьком индексов по возрастанию цены
size_t* sort_data(Journal* data, size_t len)
{
    size_t* srt = new size_t[len];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        srt[i] = i;
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len - i; j++)
        {
            if (data[srt[j]].Cost > data[srt[j + 1]].Cost)
            {
                int tmp = srt[j];
                srt[j] = srt[j + 1];
                srt[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return srt;
}

//Сохранение данных в двоичном формате. Кроме введенного количества дешевых
void save_bin(Journal* data, size_t len, ostream& ost)
{
    size_t excluded; //количество исключенных журналов
    size_t included; //количество сохраняемых журналов
    size_t* sorted = sort_data(data, len); // массив с отсортированными индексами
    cout << "Введите количество исключаемых дешевых журналов" << endl;
    //ввод количества исключаемых
    do
    {
        cin >> excluded;
        if (excluded >= len)
        {
            cout << "Значение превышает допустимое количество: " << len << endl;
            cout << "Повторите ввод" << endl;
        }

    } while (excluded >= len);
    //подсчет сохраняемых
    included = len - excluded;
    //запись количества сохраняемых в бинарном виде
    ost.write((char*)&included, sizeof(len));
    //запись информации о журналах
    for (size_t i = excluded; i < len; i++)
    {
        //Запись отдельного элемента массива
        ost.write((char*)&data[sorted[i]], sizeof(Journal));
    }
    //финализация записи в бинарный поток
    ost.flush();
    delete sorted;
}



int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;

    int stateMenu;

    //Массив структур

    size_t number_elements = 0;
    Journal* journal_elements;

    while (stateMenu = Menu())
    {
        switch (stateMenu)
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            //TODO: Режим работы 1
            cout << "Режим работы 1" << endl;

            input.open("D:\\Учёба 1 курс\\ОП\\2 Семестр\\Практическая Структуры\\Практическая_структуры\\In.txt.txt", ios::in);

            if (!input.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Входной файл не открыт!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                output.open("D:\\Учёба 1 курс\\ОП\\2 Семестр\\Практическая Структуры\\Практическая_структуры\\Out_bin.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
            }

            if (!output.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Выходной файл не открыт!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Считывание данных из текстового файла в массив структур" << endl;
                journal_elements = load_txt(input, number_elements);
            }

            if (number_elements == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Вывод данных на экран таблицей" << endl;
                print_data(journal_elements, number_elements);

                cout << "Сохранение данных в двоичный файл" << endl;
                save_bin(journal_elements, number_elements, output);
            }

            if (number_elements) {
                delete[] journal_elements;
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            //TODO: Режим работы 2
            cout << "Режим работы 2" << endl;

            input.open("D:\\Учёба 1 курс\\ОП\\2 Семестр\\Практическая Структуры\\Практическая_структуры\\Out_bin.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

            if (!input.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Входной файл не открыт!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Считывание данных из двоичного файла в массив структур" << endl;

                journal_elements = load_bin(input, number_elements);
            }

            if (number_elements == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Вывод данных в виде таблицы" << endl;
                print_data(journal_elements, number_elements);
            }

            if (number_elements)
            {
                delete[] journal_elements;
            }
            break;
        }

        if (input.is_open())
        {
            input.close();
        }
        if (output.is_open())
        {
            output.close();
        }
    }
}
```